# Python3: Writing Nested Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write the following nested dictionary to a CSV with headers.

```
headers = [ 'Location', 'Agent', 'Sales', 'Renewals', 'Leaves']
data = {'Location1'  : {'Bob': {'Sales': 2, 'Renewals': 1, 'Leaves': 1},
                        'Jim': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 2, 'Leaves': 3}},
        'Location, 2': {'Tod': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 3, 'Leaves': 1},
                        'Joe': {'Sales': 3, 'Renewals': 4, 'Leaves': 2}},
        'Location 3' : {'Bill': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 4, 'Leaves': 5}}
        }
```

I'm unfamiliar with the csv module and the guides I've looked up seem to be dated or does work with a dictionary this nested.

I'm expecting the following output:

```
Location, Agent, Sales, Renewals, Leaves
Location1, Bob, 2, 1, 1
Location1, Jim, 1, 2, 3
Location2, Tod, 1, 3, 1
```

EDIT:
Modified data dict to better reflect what is being used and use best practices.

Comment: Your dictionary contains duplicate keys (`Location1`)

Comment: Thank you for the catch @Andrej Kesely, I have my sample data wrong again, there should only be one "location1." Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found:

```
import csv

data = {'Location1': {'Bob': {'Sales': 2, 'Renewals': 1, 'Leaves': 1},
                     'Jim': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 2, 'Leaves': 3}},
        'Location, 2': {'Tod': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 3, 'Leaves': 1},
                        'Joe': {'Sales': 3, 'Renewals': 4, 'Leaves': 2}},
        'Location 3': {'Bill': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 4, 'Leaves': 5}}
        }

headers = ['Location', 'Agent', 'Sales', 'Renewals', 'Leaves']

# Initialize an empty list to store the reformatted data
formatted_data = []

for location, agents in data.items():
    for agent, values in agents.items():
        row = [location, agent, values['Sales'], values['Renewals'], values['Leaves']]
        formatted_data.append(row)

# Write the data to a CSV file
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

    # Write the headers
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    # Write the formatted data
    csv_writer.writerows(formatted_data)
```

The output is exactly what I'm looking for:

```
Location,Agent,Sales,Renewals,Leaves
Location1,Bob,2,1,1
Location1,Jim,1,2,3
"Location, 2",Tod,1,3,1
"Location, 2",Joe,3,4,2
Location 3,Bill,1,4,5
```

Thank you to everyone. The discussion and answer really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the csv library by manually creating the output with a for loop:

```
# Declare headers and data
headers = ['Location', 'Agent', 'Sales', 'Renewals', 'Leaves']
data = {'Location1': {'Bob': {'Sales': 2, 'Renewals': 1, 'Leaves': 1}},
        'Location1': {'Jim': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 2, 'Leaves': 3}},
        'Location2': {'Tod': {'Sales': 1, 'Renewals': 3, 'Leaves': 1}}
        }

# Add the headers to output
output = ','.join(headers)

# Cycle through data
for key, value in data.items():
    # Declare the items of the row
    row = [key, *value.keys(), *list(value.values())[0].values()]

    # Convert all ints to strings
    row = [str(x) for x in row]

    # Add the data to output
    output += '\n' + ','.join(row)

# Write the output to a file
with open('data.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(output)
```

This writes the data to `data.csv` in csv format:

```
Location,Agent,Sales,Renewals,Leaves
Location1,Bob,2,1,1
Location2,Jim,1,2,3
Location3,Tod,1,3,1
```

Note that you have a duplicate key in the `data` dictionary, which is generally not good practice but acceptable when exporting it to a csv file. There are also no spaces included in the result, because you'd have a space in front of each value.

Please use the checkmark to accept my answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: What if the name of a location or an agent contains a comma? `csv` is a module for good reasons. The CSV format isn't just about joining values together with commas.

Comment: This data didn't contain any commas, and I'm unfamiliar with the library. The csv format is pretty much just joined values with commas. Adding quotes wouldn't be hard either by doing `row = [f'"x"' for x in row if ',' in x]`

Comment: And what about cases where the names contain double quotes? The point is to not reinvent the wheel when a perfectly fine solution is readily available with all the corner cases handled for you.

Comment: I don't like to rely on a lot of external libraries and the OP mentioned that the csv library didn't have guides of dictionaries this nested

Comment: The `csv` module is a standard library that is part of every Python release, hardly "external" (e.g. unlike `pandas`). If you want to implement a CSV emitter yourself, be prepared to handle all the corner cases or your code would never be fit for any serious production use.

Comment: All the OP needs is the code that flattens the input data structure. Once flattened, it can be passed on to `csv.writer.writerows` for output.

Comment: Above is just an example of my real data, I do have one location with a comma so I updated the example data, thank you @blhsing.
Also, if flattening the dict works, I could probably use the module "flatdict." We are trying to stay away from using Pandas just because it's a big module. It makes me sad but just need to find work arounds.

Comment: With how I modified the data dict to better reflect how the data is actually being stored, and following best practices, I'm getting this output for location1: `Location1,Bob,Jim,2,1,1`